# Parsing in powershell

Tags: powershell

How can get the Skuname from the following text using powershell?

Input: [{\"sku\":\"sku7120234\"
Parsed Out should be: sku7120234

Also, I was given a timestamp of \"timeStamp\":1447964164371}. Can any one advise on how to get the integer value in a date format.

Comment: So you are trying to parse a json-like string, right?...if so, you just need: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849898.aspx

Comment: Hi, ca you please include a sample input file, the desired output, and the code you have tried so far ? (you can use the edit button on your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a specific File Type or Structure you should post this and the desired output as mentioned in the comments.

Simply parsing like you asked:

```
$str = '[{\"sku\":\"sku7120234\"'
```

Option 1 - Split String:

```
($str -split '\\')[3] -replace '"'
```

Option 2 - Regex Match:

```
[regex]::Match($str,'sku\d+').Groups[0].Value
```

Results:

```
sku7120234
```

---

To get your Millisecond TimeStamp to DateTime you can do this:

```
$ts = '\"timeStamp\":1447964164371}'
$epoch = [regex]::Match($ts,'\d+').Groups[0].Value
[datetime] $origin = '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000'
[datetime] $result = $origin.AddMilliseconds($epoch)
```

Result:

```
#Datetime type object result
$result
Thursday, November 19, 2015 8:16:04 PM
#or formatted string
$result.ToString()
11/19/2015 8:16:04 PM
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helps

Comment: No problem, please mark as an answer if it solved your question.

Comment: $promotions = Import-Csv "C:\Users\sabobba\Documents\rexonlinestore.csv" | foreach {
New-Object PSObject -prop @{
UserId = $_.UserId;

$str = '[{\"sku\":\"$_.Sku\"';
($str -split '\\')[3] -replace '"'
Sku = [regex]::Match($str,'sku\d+').Groups[0].Value;


$ts = '\"timeStamp\":$_.Timestamp}'
$epoch = [regex]::Match($ts,'\d+').Groups[0].Value
[datetime] $origin = '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000'
[datetime] $result = $origin.AddMilliseconds($epoch)

$result

} | Export-Csv -Path ".\simpletest.csv" -NoTypeInformation

Comment: I have the data in the below format -   UserId Sku Timestamp
b9ebd967-9106-1033-ee82-27e40f5b9202 [{\"sku\":\"sku7120234\" \"timeStamp\":1447964164371}]
b363d76b-9138-0053-2d43-cd3771c7cabc [{\"sku\":\"sku7520274\" \"timeStamp\":1457364678459}

Comment: and wanted to export the output by parsing the two fields sku and timestamp iteratively.  I wrote the script pointed above and getting errors. Please advise.